# How to stabilize detected edges/corner points

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a question based on edge detection. I am generating some lines on an image and I calculate the gradients along the line. My searched points are the minimum of the gradients. The following picture illustrates what I mean:
[image: The blue lines illustrates where in the image I am calculating the gradients. The graph shows the calculated gradients. The red point is my searched point, which is the point where the gradient is minimal.]

Here is the code how I am calculating the points:

```
    sub_img[:,] = median[y, a]
    cv2.line(img,(a,y[0]),(a,y[-1]),(0,0,255),3)
    grad= np.gradient(sub_img)
    edge = np.min(grad)
    y_point = np.where(grad == edge)
```

Now I have the following problem: When I am applying my code in a camera stream then the detection of my searched points have some tolerance about approximately 1 to 2 pixels.

For my project I have to be very accurate and I need same iterative results for the stream (the scene is not moving). Do you know how I can stabilize the detection of my points?

I am using the best for me available Hardware with high resolution and so on. So please only hints which are Software-based or the necessary mathematics.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`np.gradient` uses the finite differences approximation to compute the derivative (central differences except at the first and last points). This is very sensitive to noise. You will want to add some regularization to the operation to make it more robust against noise.

There are many regularized derivative operators defined in the image processing field. The most famous would be the Sobel operator. The best one [in many different ways](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22/) is the Gaussian gradient operator. The Gaussian is the optimal regularizing filter, its sigma parameter controls the amount of regularization.

The Gaussian gradient yields the exact gradient of the smoothed image. Since the edge that you are measuring is straight, the smoothing will not displace it: the local extremum will match exactly with the location of the edge.

Because of the Gaussian regularization, the local extremum will be smooth, and you will be able to determine the its location with sub-pixel precision. The actual precision depends only on the amount of noise and the amount of regularization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it today and give feedback.